# Как показать блоки по очереди?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как можно показать блоки по очереди?

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: Что значит "по очереди"? Один на одном и поочерёдно показывать только один, скрывая остальные? Или Поочерёдно каждый добавлять?

Comment: Показывать один за другим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот у меня где-то было интересное такое решение. Автора правда не знаю. Оно?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fadeInDelay = function() {
    var init = function() {
      $(this).hide().delay($(this).data('delay')).fadeIn();
    };
    return this.each(init);
  };
}(jQuery));
$('div').fadeInDelay();
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-delay="1000">1</div>
<div data-delay="2000">2</div>
<div data-delay="3000">3</div>
<div data-delay="4000">4</div>
```

Comment: По моему мнению, единственный минус - это требуется подключать jquery. Вариант ниже - боле предпочтительней

Answer (score 7):

Вариант без js, на чистом css:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 1s linear forwards;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    var duration = 2000; //'slow'
    $("div").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(duration * index).fadeIn(duration).fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

```css
    div {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Если показывать все:

```js
    var duration = 2000; //'slow'
    $("div").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(duration * index).fadeIn(duration);
    });
```

```css
    div {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: green;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```